# Moving UIView and subviews periodically

Tags: ios, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I am building a word tetris kind of an app. Now I have to move a Uiview containing 8 uibuttons towards the bottom of the screen based on time and also track the position of uibuttons as the user taps specified button.
Am I suppose to use Block based animation or core animation to do the task.
Currently if I am animating frame and center of superview it seems like I have to do the same for the subviews as well inside the block.
Any input would be handy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIView block animation to animate a view and it's subviews quite simply.

However, neither UIView animation nor core animation will let the user click on buttons as they are animating. Button actions don't work at all on "in flight" animations. There's no automatic way to do that. (At least none that I know of.)

Instead, you have to add a tap gesture recognizer to the parent view, and do hit testing on the presentation layer of your parent view to see which sublayer of the presentation layer is tapped.